# Аналог Fragments (Android) в Qt

Tags: qt, gui

Присутствует ли в Qt некое подобие фрагментов Android? Скажем, необходимо, чтобы в одном окне можно было переключаться между разными макетами интерфейса.

Возможно, существует какой-то определенный подход для реализации подобного функционала на десктопных платформах?

Comment: QStackedLayout https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html

Comment: Или QStackedWidget https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html